# xamarin access protected firebase realtime database with nuget package FirebaseAuthentication.net

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

im beginner in firebase and im using two nuget packages FirebaseAuthentication.net and FirebaseDatabase.net .
im trying to write to a protected firebase realtime database that has a rule that look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

i randomly tryed SignInWithOAuthAsync method however it throws an Exception  `[ mail auth type connot be used like this. use method specifc to email & password authentication]`

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(webApiKey));
                var savedfirebaseauth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebaseAuth>(Preferences.Get("MyFirebaseRefreshToken", ""));
                await authProvider.SignInWithOAuthAsync(FirebaseAuthType.EmailAndPassword, savedfirebaseauth.FirebaseToken);
                

                //inserting info into the database
               
                await firebaseClient.Child("users").Child("some uid1").PutAsync(new userinfo
                {

                    firstName = "noor",
                    secondName = "mohammed"
                });

                //clear the entry
                recordData.Text = "";

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
```

pleace let me know if my question needs more Clarificatio thanks in advance.

Comment: "it throws an Exception" - without knowing the details of the exception there is not much we can do to help you

Comment: this the exception [ mail auth type connot be used like this. use method specifc to email & password authentication]